# vim, pasting script.py to python interpreter loses formatting

Tags: python, vim

I'm trying to remap a key to yank/put selected text from a script into a Python interpreter using ConqueTerm. Everything is fine, except this...

```
def main():
    print "Testing 123"

main()
```

turns into this...

```
>>> def main():    print "Testing 123"main()
```

in the interpreter. How can I keep the multi-line formatting?

Note: I've already tried plugins like vim-conque-repl and vim-ipython, but I haven't been able to get either of them to work correctly.

Comment: Here's what I was trying to use: vmap <F12> "*y<C-Tab>p

Comment: What does the `<C-Tab>` do?  Is it related to vim or ConqueTerm?  Before making a `:vmap`, try to get it to work "by hand."  Does it?  Maybe it is a line-ending problem.  After the `"*y`, try replacing NL with CRNL:  `let @* = substitute(@*, "\n", "\r\n", 'g')`.

Comment: <C-Tab> moves between windows like moving between tabs in a web browser. Apparently it's only a ConqueTerm command, so I've replaced it with <C-w><C-w> in the following code: `vmap <silent> <leader>m "*y<C-w><C-w>p`. I tried your recommendation for fixing a potential line-ending problem, but that didn't change anything. It's worth mentioning that the multiline-turning-into-single-line problem is only an issue on Windows, but I got it to work perfectly on Linux. My work computer is Windows so I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: I ultimately decided to use Cygwin on my work computer. Conque pastes as expected now, but I still don't know why it didn't work on Windows. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just answered there, see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36489654/6174890