# Sending multiple python lines with ConqueTerm

Tags: python, vim, ipython, conque

I'm using vim with ConqueTerm and ipython (--pylab if it matters) on Ubuntu 14.04. When I select multiple lines and send them using F9, everything pastes in the same line, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056691/vim-pasting-script-py-to-python-interpreter-loses-formatting). I could try remapping as the poster did for that question, but I don't have this issue with matlab on the same machine or with ConqueTerm+ipython on mac. Is there a way to fix this so I can continue using F9? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### The solution

It was my first experience using vimscript, but I was able to modify the plugin so it can send the selected lines properly.

I changed the `send_selected` function in the `conque.vim(or another mirror)\autoload\conque_term.vim` to this: https://gist.github.com/freencis/28e351e3bb267a8522e1dff53436fb8d

The function name is the same, just go there and replace it.

### What I did

I will skip the "explaing what was wrong" part, mostly because I didn't fully grasp the original implementation.

So, after searching a bit on the internet about how I could access the file's text from a plugin, I ended up finding a way to get the text from specific lines from the file: using the `getline` function. Luckly there were already a Conque's function to send the line to the terminal and execute it (used by the 's send_file), so I just used it.

Then It was just a matter of knowing which lines were selected and get those. Which led me to the `line` function, which returns the line number in a different ways. One of these was by marker, in this case the '<, '> markers from the visual selection. Unfortunately I also don't know how to explain these, but calling `line("'<")` and `line("'>")` returned me the selection's start and end lines respectively.

And that was the vimscript programming part, the :help is really a life saver. The traditional programming was just looping through the line numbers, getting the text from those and sending them to the terminal.

### Notes

It was my first ever experience with vimscript (I've only been using vim for a month), so I'm sure it might not the proper way to do it, plus I replaced a functionality, so I'm just sharing it as a quick hack. Any feedback is appreciated.

Props to http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/, it helped me a lot with the language, I never expected it to be that accessible

And sorry for any bad English. peace